# Add EditText to LoginActivity Template

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android-edittext

How can I modify  a LoginActivity Template for adding a new EditText and a CheckBox? The thing is that am trying to create a logging and register app with the same activity but instead of using a normal activity am using a template of android studio LoginActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the following code for adding new Edit Text :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/Edit_ID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="Text"
                    android:maxLines="1" android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Login template use new Design Library thats why u need to use above way to add new Edit texts .

Comment: @EsmerlinPaniagua: If you found the answer through my post then please tick my answer  .